# MYSQL 8 in WSL Ubuntu 20.04 change directory

Tags: mysql

I managed to change the Mysql directory normally as shown in some tutorials, however it does not start, I changed the mysql 8 data's directory that is in /var/lib/mysql to /mnt/d/mysql, either with a copy of the databases that were running or the location zeroed, it does not start. The error log gives the following message:

`[System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)  (Ubuntu). mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /mnt/d/mysql/VERIFIQIMOVEIS.pid ended mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'. mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /mnt/d/mysql [Warning] [MY-010139] [Server] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 8161) [Warning] [MY-010142] [Server] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 4000) [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) starting as process 21204 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /mnt/d/mysql/ is case insensitive [Warning] [MY-010075] [Server] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 7e204e29-9132-11ed-aeb5-32ceaa8792ed. [ERROR] [MY-011011] [Server] Failed to find valid data directory. [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed. [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting`

I tried to set permissions with

`sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /mnt/d/mysql sudo chmod -R 755 /mnt/d/mysql`

I went to /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/alias and put the new path on the line
`alias /var/lib/mysql/ -> /mnt/d/mysql/,`

Comment: try `mysqld --initialize`

Comment: I'm assuming by the "case insensitive" warning and the mount point that this fat32 storage? Good attempts with the permissions/apparmour but it might not be enough. Using a Linux filesystem (btrfs,ext3/4, xfs) are recommended.

Comment: @danblack its a NTFS storage, i try make work in WSL, because of the customer's need to be like this, so I have a VM with Windows Server 2019, using WSL to run Ubuntu 20.04 with LAMP, with MYSQL version 8.0.31

Answer (score 0):

Well, after many attempts trying to make MySQL 8 work, changing its directory (appdir) to another HD (D:) using the path mnt/d/, I uninstalled mysql and installed MariaDB, which in my case came to work, I had just create a user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' and set the same password that appears in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf this experience of mine is recorded, I hope one day it will help someone.

Comment: Note occasional users are reporting [WSL problems](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8443) under MariaDB, there's no reason to expect they wouldn't apply to MySQL too. A native MariaDB on Windows is much more tested.